# How to get child item id from the expandable list view if the child's are different layouts, while click?

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, get-childitem

I am working with custom expandable list view in android. In my expandable list view has items with linear layouts.

You can find my expandable listview here. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2NGqFM-F0bNcUZqUlRPaUZYUjg/edit?usp=sharing

In the image the child item is one linearlayout. How can i get individual items like main,wall,table and entry items id. So that i will perform individual operations.

You can find my adapter here.

```
package com.newsmartcontrol;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.smartcontrol.R;



public class ExpandsAdapter implements ExpandableListAdapter
{
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public ExpandsAdapter (Context context, LayoutInflater layoutInflater)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
}


@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 4;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View view, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.expands_group, null);
    TextView title_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_name);
    if(groupPosition == 0) {
        title_name.setText("Lights");
    }
    if(groupPosition == 1) {
        title_name.setText("AC-Thermostat");
    }
    if(groupPosition == 2) {
        title_name.setText("Drapery");
    }
    if(groupPosition == 3) {
        title_name.setText("TV");
    }
    view.invalidate();
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if(groupPosition == 0) {
        view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.lights_layout, null);
    }
    if(groupPosition == 1) {
        view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.ac_thermostat_layout, null);
    }
    if(groupPosition == 2) {
        view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.drapery_layout, null);
    }
    if(groupPosition == 3) {
        view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.tv_layout, null);
    }
    view.invalidate();
    return view;

}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public long getCombinedChildId(long groupId, long childId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getCombinedGroupId(long groupId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


 }
```

And my activity is here.

```
 public class ExpandsMainActivity extends Activity
{
ExpandableListView  expandableListView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.expands_main);
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    ExpandsAdapter adapter = new ExpandsAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater());
    expandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
          }
```

Please tell me how can i get individual items of the child sub item id in the expandable listview. So that i will write the click operation for main,wall and remaining all items individually.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was using  the onChildClick parameter childPosition, like this:

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener(){
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView  parent, View v,
    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
    {
            int childItemID=childPosition;
    }
});
```